# no module pygame in Pycharm

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

I try to work for the first time with Kivy, I install it but when I run the program I have this error message:
[image]

And I try to install pygame, but I still have the same error:
[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Can you `import` either one in a .py script run from the command line?

Comment: you may have installed many Pythons - Mac should have installed default one and you use Anaconda in PyCharm. Maybe you installed PyGame for different version than you use in PyCharm.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 2):

To ensure proper setup, you can download pygame from PyCharm directly.

[image: Add a the PyGame package by clicking the '+' button]

[image: Enter PyGame and press 'Install Package']

You should now be able to import pygame and use them in your scripts.

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work. Thanks, man!

Comment: @Frecklefoot, super late on the reply but glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it's due to not having the interpreter installed.

On terminal:

- pip install pylint (to install globally)
- Restart pycharm and click on install package "pygame" over the error it shows. This also applies for most of the other packages.

If you are using VsCode or any other, just pip install pygame (or any other needed) and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

For PyCharm, go to:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Project: Project_Name
4. Click the '+' icon (located on the bottom side). Then will Appear new window.
5. Search pygame on this window
6. Then click 'Install Package'
7. close the window and run your code.